# Best practices for storing Auth0 settings in a desktop app?

Tags: wpf, windows, winforms, oauth-2.0, auth0

I'm currently storing Auth0 settings (domain, clientId, scope, realm, audience) for my desktop app in app.config, like:

```
        <add key="Auth0:Domain" value="" />
        <add key="Auth0:ClientId" value="" />
        <add key="Auth0:Scope" value="" />
        <add key="Auth0:Realm" value="" />
        <add key="Auth0:Audience" value="" />
```

My colleague thinks it's not a wise idea to give the user an option to change it by doing that - he prefers to hardcode them.

I think nobody will bother to fiddle with it, it's public information and there's not much harm anyone can do with this.

What are the best practices here?

Comment: What's this `ClientID`? Isn't that something you'd want to keep private?

Comment: It's the id of the Auth0 client (this app), generally public information.

Comment: Isn't that also the ID used to calculate any charges that apply? Is it not also the ID used to implement throttling in case the client uses up more resources than agreed upon? As such, unless there's also a client secret involved, the `ClientID` allows others to steal the service you subscribed/paid for, or run a DoS attack against your application.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options with not much difference in security terms:

- Hard coding (uurrgh)
- Separate config file
- Embedded resource

The cleanest option is usually to download settings from an API, since it makes updates and versioning easier:

- GET /apI/desktop/configuration

The only info about remote systems your app then needs to know is its (Entry Point) API URL.

With desktop and mobile apps I like to have a (hidden away) option for testing where you can switch environments. This can be a settings page or a deployed config file - but the only editable value is the API URL.

This fits well with Continuous Delivery best practice, where you build your binaries once, then combine with configuration during the deployment step. It should also meet your colleague's concerns.